# Django define update_fields when creating objects in model

Tags: django, django-models

I am using a SQL Server table with period columns, and my model in Django is defined as

```py
class Client(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=40)
    sys_start_time = models.DateTimeField(db_column="SysStartTime")
    sys_end_time = models.DateTimeField(db_column="SysEndTime")

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "client"
```

where `sys_start_time` and `sys_end_time` are period columns. Due to sql server rules, any query defining values for these columns are invalid, which means that the sql query django generated when creating or updating this model won't work.

I managed to exclude them in `update_fields` when performing update so that django will generate queries without period columns, but I can't use the same `update_fields` parameter when creating an object, otherwise I get an error saying

> Cannot force both insert and updating in model saving.

Is there a way to let django ignore certain fields when creating an object?

OR

Is there a way to tell Django to send `DEFAULT` (sql server keyword, not string) as the value for these period columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who faces the same problem, I ended up overriding `_do_insert()` method in the model to take out period columns out from query when creating new records

```py
class Client(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=40)
    sys_start_time = models.DateTimeField(db_column="SysStartTime")
    sys_end_time = models.DateTimeField(db_column="SysEndTime")

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "client"

    def _do_insert(self, manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw):
        period_columns = ["sys_start_time", "sys_end_time"]
        non_ignored_fields = [
            f for f in fields if (f.name not in period_columns and f.attname not in period_columns )
        ]
        return super(ModelWithSaveIgnoreFields, self)._do_insert(
            manager, using, non_ignored_fields, returning_fields, raw
        )
```

For update, defining `update_fields` still works perfectly.